# Cannot install nvidia graphics driver 390 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, xorg, 18.04

After facing issues with nvidia 396, I wanted to move back to nvidia 390 on Ubuntu 18.04.
I purged nvidia from the system, moving back to the default xorg driver.

I then added the repository ($ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa ), and tried to install 390 by

> > $ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390

However, this is also installing nvidia 396 on my machine. 
How can I install 390?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
What was happening was that another ppa was interfering and the download was taking place from that repo.

It was the System76 Pop repository. I removed it from Software and Updates.

After that, running

> > $ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390

installs the 390 driver as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as of now many of the bugs related to this issue (NVIDIA Graphics) have been fixed and the installation procedure is fairly easy.

> 1.**Entering Grub Boot Parameters** - This can be done by going to the grub menu at boot (press `Esc` or `Shit` at boot) here press `e`. 
>  2. **Enabling Text Mode Booting** - Here add a `3` after `quiet splash` and press `F10` to reboot using the new parameters. 
> 3. **Purge NVIDIA**- Now login to the text only mode, and purge all the NVIDIA drivers completely using the `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`, and reboot. While rebooting follow step 1, here edit the parameters and add the command `nomodeset` before `qiet splash`, and press `F10`
>    to reboot the using the new parameters. 
>  4. **Installing Nvidia Drivers**- once in the system run commands in the terminal `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` now.
>
> > 1. Add the drivers repository to Ubuntu, run the commands `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and `sudo apt update`. 
> >     Now, do not update graphic drivers via the terminal, instead search for Software & Updates in the Ubuntu GUI. here go to the additional drivers tab. Here you will find the set of NVIDIA drivers for your system. select the `nvidia-drivers-390` or use `nvidia-driver-415` i think that one is the latest. *(Make sure that you do not select or keep selection in `Using X.Org X server` - selection)*
> > 2. The installation will take a while once the installation is complete, reboot the system.
> > 3. Now it isn't necessary to add nomodeset to boot parameters, the Ubuntu Os should boot properly and without any error.
> > 4. If you have added `nomodeset` parameters to Grub, remove it in this step and keep the `quiet splash` parameter alone.*(or else nvidia driver wont load)*
> > 5. Once you have completed the login, enter the Ubuntu desktop, search for the NVIDIA Xserver application, to monitior the nvidia GPU.